# Why isn't it possible to generate required messages using ts-proto?

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers

According to the [ts-proto documentation](https://github.com/stephenh/ts-proto?tab=readme-ov-file#current-status-of-optional-values): "Required messages: not available". E.g.:

```
message NestedObject {
  string id = 1;
}

message RootObject {
  NestedObject obj = 1;
}
```

results in

```
export interface RootObject {
  obj: NestedObject | undefined;
}
...
```

This stops me from accurately generating any non-primitive data structure into typescript and I have to either write a new set of types with some kind of decoding layer (which kinda defeats the point of generating the code) or override the type system.

Why is this the case? Unless I'm misunderstanding something it seems like being able to accurately represent nested data would be a key feature of code generation. Was hoping someone could explain why it's not possible.

(as an aside, this also applies to `google.protobuf.Timestamp`, which is converted to `Date | undefined` instead of `Date` - if there is a way to stop this from happening that would already be very helpful)

Thanks!